# How to efficiently create a list in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, list, textview

I'm relatively new to Objective-C programming and iOS, and am working on my third app which involves a list of around 300 different words which you can scroll through downwards. However, I don't want to have to create 30 TextViews in a ScrollView, and individually name them all. Which technique would I therefore use to efficiently create a list of items?

All help appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a table view? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/abouttableviewsiphone/abouttableviewsiphone.html

Comment: This looks like it should do well! Thanks friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need a `UITableViewController`. These are responsible for producing the typical 'lists' of objects that people use in the vast majority of apps. `UITableViewControllers` really aren't that complicated but for a beginner they can take some time to get used to. Most beginners find them difficult but try [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) for an idea. You can go from there onto other things.

A quick side note: The `UITableViewController` stuff is very fundamental to iOS. Many developers are not as comfortable with using it as they should be. If you think it will be useful for what you are trying to build then take a good amount of time to familiarise yourself with it. The likelihood is that you will use it over and over again.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, friend. Have a tick! And this is definitely useful - Creating lists in Android was rather inefficient, given I didn't know about a tool like this.

Answer (score 0):

The `UITableViewController` will probably do what you need. You will need to set up an array of words to use as your data source.

[A decent tutorial project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) is available from Apple.